# pyinsetller change application icon

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am using pyinsetller to package my python program. This is the command I use. In the picture is my directory structure. I am sure there are no errors in the parameters I entered, but the result still does not change the icon of the application. Why is this?[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --icon=icon.ico demo.py
```

Like a default parameter, clearly show that the parameter is icon. In your case it is probably being parsed in some other way.But add '--onefile' do not forget
Or else even this works if both are in different locations:

```
pyinstaller --onefile -i"C:\your_path\icon.ico" C:\Your_file_path\demo.py
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used the --onefile parameter to generate the icon, thank you for your help.

But when I use the --dir parameter, it does not generate an icon.

After investigation, I found that publishing an exe under Windows requires making an ICO icon, which is composed of many different pixel pngs. The ico I used above was obtained by using a pixel png conversion. The problem is here, you can find tools Combining ICO icons.Thank you very much!

Comment: There are many websites which can convert the png image into ico or something.. if you need to do it again